# Git shallow checkout a remote branch

Tags: git

Suppose I have a remote git repo which is extremely big (e.g. > 10 GiB) and the network connection is unstable which means any attempt of fetching the whole repo is deemed to fail (i.e., not possible to execute anything like `git fetch --all` or `git fetch --unshallow`).

I however managed to get a shallow clone by issuing `git clone --depth 1`. However, this shallow clone does not have any branches other than `master`. Neither `git checkout <branch>` nor `git checkout -b <branch> --track <origin/branch>` works. No branch is showing for `git branch -r` either.

It is possible to run `git fetch --depth 1 origin <branch>`, but after that the desired branch does not show in `git branch` or `git branch -r` either, and any attempt to checkout that branch still fails.

How can I checkout a remote branch in this situation?

Remarks,

`git clone -b <branch> --depth 1` does work, but even a shallow clone takes hours to complete (if it completes at all), so I would like to reuse as many local objects as possible.

Comment: Sound like your repo has many binary objects. Git can not do much with binary objects, so you have to bear the data transfer overheads.

Comment: Note that Git doesn't have "shallow checkout" (it does have "sparse checkout" but that's something else entirely). Your issue here is due to the fact that a shallow clone is, by default, also a *single-branch* clone. See the duplicates I've linked. However, you may just want to add `--no-single-branch` to your initial clone call.

Comment: You might also consider making one full clone once, and then using `--reference` (with or without `--dissociate`). These get a little more complicated though. If you do make a reference clone to use, it's a good idea to update it periodically, so that the reference does not get too far behind the original.

Comment: It might also be worth trying out [partial cloning](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone).

Comment: You can use `git fetch --depth 1 origin <branch>:refs/heads/<branch>` or `git fetch --depth 1 origin <branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch>` to create the branch or remote branch. If you just want to checkout the fetched commit, you could also use `git fetch --depth 1 origin <branch> && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`.